# Is there an equivalent to umask for Windows, or another solution?

Tags: vb.net, permissions, ntfs, umask

I have a VB.NET application that creates folder trees and sets permissions.

I want the permissions on the folders the app creates to be read only for a normal user.  But I want a user to be able to create and delete files/directories within this tree that they have made.

The problem I'm running into is the files/directories the user creates have the same permissions as the parent directory (Windows umask is to copy parent dir).

So either the user has too much power and can delete folders from the tree the app made.  Or the user doesn't have enough power and can't delete a file/folder they created within the app created directory tree.

I haven't been able to solve this with ACL Propagate and Inherit properties:
[VB.NET app is setting restricted file permissions on a directory, which is incorrectly restricting user created files in the same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551429/vb-net-app-is-setting-restricted-file-permissions-on-a-directory-which-is-incor)

Any ideas or another way to attack this problem?
Thanks, Mike

Comment: There's a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551429/vb-net-app-is-setting-restricted-file-permissions-on-a-directory-which-is-incor